# Android: How to make sure in any case getActivity in Fragment should not return null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am not much experienced in Android Programming. And Currently I am working on an Application which makes use of `Fragment`s. Sometimes i see that `getActivity()` returns null randomly. It happens once in thousand times or so. For now it's fine because there are no much users using it. But when app will go live may create many issues.

So my question is what is the best programming practice to make sure `getActivity()` never returns null in any case?

I searched online but everybody talks about solving issue in their existing code. If anyone has a generalised way of explaining it, then please let me know. Thanks you so much in advance

Comment: There is a method in fragment called onAttach and onDetach and the are respectively associates and detaches fragment from activity, so you could create instance variable and hold in it your activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not random, it means that your `Fragment` is not currently attached to your `Activity`.
There is a ton of answer on that topic on SO, that I don't consider to be a good practice, is to override `onAttach()` and keep a reference to your `Activity`, like that :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}
```

I think you should not do that and just check if `getActivity()` doesn't return null.

If you just need a `Context` reference you could however to that :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
}
```

And use you `mContext` which is the application `Context`.

**PS:**
If you run your application on a device with **API 23**,  `onAttach(Context)` will be called. On previous APIs `onAttach(Activity)` will be called.

**EDIT :**

In that case you should use Loaders :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4eAtMHU5gI
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: I do have on Attach method in my Fragment code.  I also make sure that I call getActivity after onAttach method gets called. The current issue in my code is that I have an async task in my code and I call getActivity() on Post Execute method and there it returns null if user goes to next activity before async task finishes.

Comment: See my edit, AsyncTask are not the correct solution for you issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should override onActivityCreated and call `getActivity()` from there, in this way you can be sure `getActitity()` never returns null, because called after parent activity `onCreate` has done.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // call getActivity() here
}
```

Here is supporting quote from android doc([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))):

> public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving views or restoring state. It is also useful for fragments that use setRetainInstance(boolean) to retain their instance, **as this callback tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity instance.** This is called after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) and before onViewStateRestored(Bundle).